# retrieve `e.target` from jQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a jquery element. The `updateHandler` function expects a DOM element with `e.target.name` and `e.target.value`

How can I pass the `e` fetched with jQuery to `updateHandler` function with `e.target`/`e.value`?

```js
let e = $('[name="amount"]')
// or
// let e = document.getElementsByName('amount') //

// modify the value of e and pass it to below
updateHandler(e[0]) // This function expects e.target
```

The error is `e.target` is undefined. In both cases using `jQuery($)` or `document.xxx`.

Comment: What you actually wants to do ?

Comment: just simple query. if I have jquery element, can I fetch the DOM element having e.target in it? because the other function where i am passing it expects e.target

Comment: then pass it like <input type="text" onInput="yourfunctionName($event)"> .... In Javascript your will get element.target in function yourfunctionName(event){ // Your code here }

Comment: Again for all of you, I can not modify `updateHandler()` funtion. and the onChange event on amount input. I just want to fetch the input element named `amount`, update it's value with formating toFixed, and pass it to `updateHandler' which expects e.target.

Comment: From the context of the error mention `e.target`, then the `updateHandler` function is expecting an **Event** object, not a jQuery/Element object.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes exactly. So that's why Can i create custom Event having `e.targt.name` and `e.target.value` in it? because I need to modify the value before passing it to `updateHandler()`

Comment: Sure you can do that it you really want to: https://jsfiddle.net/thbu6zda/. However it's an ***incredibly*** bad thing to be doing. If you really have no other choice than to do this I'd suggest restructuring your logic to avoid it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks but I am not using any button click event here. I already have the `input` element named `amount` with unformated number value and I want to modify it with decimals before passing it to `updateHandler' so there is no click event. I have to crate custom Event.

Comment: This is how you can do that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events. Again, this is a massive code smell and not something you should be doing, at all.

Comment: I don't think you really need a real event, just an object that has the right properties set. `updateHandler({target:e[0], value:e.val()})`

Answer (score 0):

> SOLUTION

As per @Ouroborus hint in above comment. this solved using below coding.
Thanks

```
let e = $('[name="amount"]')
updateHandler({target: {name: 'amount', value: parseFloat(e.val() || 0).toFixed(2)}})
```